# How to insert data from one Azure SQL Database into a different Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I realize that Azure SQL Database does not support doing an insert/select from one db into another, even if they're on the same server.  We receive data files from clients and we process and load them into a "load database".  Once the load is complete, based upon various rules, we then move the data into a production database of which there are about 20, all clones of each other (the data only goes into one of the databases).

Looking for a solution that will allow us to move the data.  There can be 500,000 records in a load file and so moving them one by one is not really feasible.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Elastic Query](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-query-overview/)? [Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-query-getting-started-vertical/) is the Getting Started guide for it. Currently you cannot perform remote writes, but you can always read data from remote tables.

Hope this helps!

Silvia Doomra